# Не получается экспортировать модель из блендер с текстурой в unity3d

Tags: unity3d, blender

пожалуйста помогите решить мою проблему. Я все обыскал и сижу над этим уже 3 день. Моя беда в том, что я не могу экспортировать очень простую модель из блендера в юнити, точнее могу, но эта модель экспортируется без текстуры, которую я наложил в блендере. Может я не в том расширении экспортирую или не применил наложение текстуры на модель в блендере. Даже модель, на которую я наложил самый обыкновенный материал в блендере (просто покрасил модель) экспортируется в юнити без этого материала, просто белая модель и все. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: хотя бы скрины вставил бы... И каким форматом экспортируешь....

Comment: просто перенеси текстуру(.png ... ) в unity и она сама оденется, если нет, то вручную назначь. Материал точно переносится

Comment: @Данил я экспортировал в юнити в формате .blend и .fbx, другими не пробовал

Comment: @Valera Kvip я изначально импортировал все текстуры в юнити, а потом уже модели. Люди говорят, что лучше текстурировать объекты в 3Д редакторе (в моем случае в блендере) потому, что там больше настроек и 3Д редактор лучше работает с текстурами, чем юнити. Я мог бы текстурировать и в юнити, но у меня не получается там правильно наложить текстуру на объект.

Comment: Блендер это святое!

Comment: @Данил так вы не знаете как мне помочь?

Comment: Воще хз, возможно баг